# Issue while trying to install anchor

Tags: anchor, solana-program, rust, javascript, solana-cli

> : build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish... error: failed to
> compile `avm v0.25.0 (https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor#c1c4f6c3)`,
> intermediate artifacts can be found at `/tmp/cargo-installLulkgh

Facing this error while trying to install anchor.

Comment: Are you using Linux based system as the Windows platform is not supported?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what did you install what you didn't but i think the avm might be missing. for more information check [this](https://github.com/LearnWithArjun/solana-env-setup) and follow step by step.